# how to test android applications?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

how to test android applications? I configured AVD emulator, the tests are no errors but when I run on the tablet - at the start of the application - exits with an error. 
I do not know what to do

Comment: I can look logcat on the tablet?

Comment: Not at the same time as running the app, and not if you're on android 4.1. You can always connect it via USB and look at it.

Comment: can you give me instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read android debugging documentation on http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html ?

You can switch on USB Debugging in Android system settings in your tablet, and directly debug your application from Eclipse on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at *Androidd Developers* official [Testing](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html) page.

There, you will find a [Testing Fundamental](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html) chapter which will teach you how to deal with the framework. Also, there is a step-by-step [testing tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html) that will be very useful to you, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to check the compatibility of the application. the application may be not compatible with your tablet version.

Try to use more emulators like Android Wear and TV

test with more API versions like 16,18, 19 and more.,

Test with many screen sizes also.,